# In Magento make Inserted Products Not Visible to Admin?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento Im inserting Products from front-end(User) And That Showing in Back-end(in Admin).Now I Want That Products Not Show To Admin? Because I Integrated Some Payment option if the user pay money for that product...that product only show to admin(Back-end)?

Comment: at admin side, why you need programming over there or you want to do it at front end ?

Comment: Sir,I want do it in front-end only:my requirements are my products store(Now Inserting) in db but not show to admin after pay money for that products then only show to admin.but My Products Showing to admin.....Thank You

Comment: First and the fore most important things : there is no point keeping entry hidden at admin. You only need to to do it at front end. can you clarify your doubt more briefly. I am not getting exactly what you want.

Comment: Work is:User can sell their products from front-end.when products cratered that shows to admin(back-end) after that  admin enable or disable user product. Still above I Completed with PHP Developing code. now what i want is when user creating the product the details store in db but not visible to admin.if user pay some money then only that product shows to admin.now i want implement that condition.

Comment: Not understanding your language. Please explain things well..

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why this needs to be done, however this can be done in the following manner :

1. Create an attribute say (admin_visibility) of (yes/no) type, set products that should be visible to the admin as YES and others to no.
2. Now override the product grid, use the addAttributeToFilter('admin_visibility', 1) function on the product collection to filter the grid, now only the products with admin_visibility set to YES will be visible to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. In my site I have developed that module by using which users can add product from front end. While adding the product i have used setVisibility to 1, i.e

```
$product->setVisibility(1);
```

From admin you have to go to app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/grid.php

Then go to the function `_prepareCollection` and change the line there from

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');
```

to

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('Visibility', 4);
```

This will solve the problem.